# ¿Cómo puedo ofuscar el código en c#?

Tags: c#, ofuscación

A)

He probado varios ofuscadores de pago y no son mejores que :

https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configuration&referringTitle=Documentation

también está este otro :

http://ntcore.com/phoenix.php

Este ultimo me parece que es mucho mejor que el primero pues me parece que no seria fácil conseguir que el código extraído con ILSPY luego pueda compilarse sin bastante trabajo.

El problema de la publicidad es que generalmente se miente en ella, y eso es lo que he encontrado en los ofuscadores que se venden.

Generalmente tienen ejemplos muy "ininteligibles" pero cuando le pones código real, yo lo sigo entendiendo muy claramente.

Los ofuscadores de pago ofrecen mucho más de lo que realmente hacen, no pude ver que el código quede ni cerca de lo que ofrecen y algunos son muy caros.

Creo que se pueden complementar con esta herramienta que es muy interesante, por lo menos para pequeñas rutinas :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/531028/Encrypted-code-compiled-at-runtime

Quisiera conocer sus experiencias "reales" al respecto, estoy cansado de las mentiras.

un ejemplo es mejor que mil palabras, observen:

sin ofuscar

```
    public Enumerados.EstadosLicencia ChequearLicencia()
    {
        return this._ChequearLicencia();
    }

    private Enumerados.EstadosLicencia _ChequearLicencia()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> datos = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        datos.Add("a0aCodigoExterno", "");
        datos = DataSqlite.leerDatos(new AControlArchivo(Application.StartupPath, "programa", "anclaje"), datos);
        string awTrial = (string)datos["a0aCodigoExterno"];
    ...
    }
```

ofuscado

```
    public Enumerados.EstadosLicencia ChequearLicencia()
    {
        return this.?511?();
    }

    private Enumerados.EstadosLicencia ?511?()
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dictionary.Add(?1437?.?1438?("qĿɯ͎ѣկ٣ݮࡧू੾ୱౡ൱๬཮"), ?1437?.?1438?(""));
        dictionary = DataSqlite.leerDatos(new AControlArchivo(Application.StartupPath, ?1437?.?1438?("xŵɩ͢Ѷբٯݠ"), ?1437?.?1438?("fŨɦͨѢը٤")), dictionary);
        string text = (string)dictionary[?1437?.?1438?("qĿɯ͎ѣկ٣ݮࡧू੾ୱౡ൱๬཮")];
        this.?750?.awCodigoExterno = text;
    ...
    }
```

B)

He probado varios programas que encriptan el ejecutable y se desencripta en memoria mientras se ejecutan pero no funcionan con .net, si ustedes saben de alguno que sí funcione, por favor comenten, quisiera agregarlo como una barrera más para proteger mi código.

C)

Buscando en internet encontré que es posible escribir parte del código en c++/cli y hacer un wrapper con c#.

Sigo tratando de encontrar un ejemplo del wrapper c++/cli con c#, aún no se de donde bajar el c++/cli, si alguien puede orientarme al respecto ???

Probé el visual c++ y se puede ver el código con el ILSPY.

Preguntas:

- ¿Han usado ofuscadores y han recibido realmente lo que les han prometido?
- ¿Existe para .net un programa que comprima/encripte el ejecutable y las librerias, que al ejecutarlo se descomprima/desencripte en memoria y se ejecute ?
- ¿Conocen un ejemplo en que se pueda ver como usar c++/cli y hacer un wrapper con c#?

Comment: Hola Hugo, este pregunta esta basada en opiniones por lo cual, no es adecuada para el sitio ya que genera discusión no objetiva. Puedes hacer esta pregunta en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) donde sera bienvenida :)

Comment: La opinión del que sabe es conocimiento, para mí que sé muy poco es importante leer a los que saben. Pero en muchos sitios encuentro que los usuarios tiene miedo de poner sus opiniones si van en contra de las corporaciones.

Comment: Cuando empecé a usar C# me encontré que era muy similar su funcionamiento con Clipper que era interpretado y eso permitía acceder a su código, lo comenté y me dijeron que el CIL era "otra cosa" pero luego me encontré con la falta de seguridad, cualquiera puede acceder al código.

Comment: Hoy luego de 3 años dedicados a escribir código en C# y a punto de empezar a vender mi software y con la promesa de que los ofuscadores realmente ofuscaban el código, empecé a probarlos y me encontré que todo era mentiras.

Comment: Yo viví la experiencia de FIDO NET donde estaba prohibido "vender", donde estaba prohibido "mentir", donde uno buscaba la palabra de los  guru's, donde uno buscaba respaldo en los colegas sin intereses económicos de por medio.

Comment: Yo busco DISCUSION OBJETIVA, claro que la busco, pues he recorrido la web y no la he encontrado.

Comment: @jasilva ya he editado la pregunta

Comment: @jasilva,  no entiendo porque la cerraron, toda pregunta solicita opiniones, se espera que las respuestas sean opiniones objetivas, parece como si apañaran las mentiras ? espero una explicación

Comment: Hola de nuevo Hugo, creo que este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) te ayudara

Comment: @jasilva, ya lo lei y mi pregunta no incumple ninguna norma, y la prueba es que tengo una respuesta y habria más si no la hubieran bloqueado,

Comment: Hola Hugo, podriamos hablar con el moderador @LuiggiMendoza para ver este tema

Comment: @HugoMariño Obtener una respuesta no es sinónimo de que la pregunta cumple con todos los criterios del sitio; lo único que significa es que simplemente un usuario decidió responder. Y en efecto es probable que tuvieras más respuestas si no hubieran cerrado la pregunta, que es justamente el objetivo de cerrar estas preguntas: no recibir respuestas a preguntas que no cumplen los criterios del sitio

Comment: Hola @Hugo. Tal como está redactada la pregunta, luce más como una discusión en busca de un buen ofuscador de código. Si eso es lo que buscas, puedes hacerlo en una sala de chat en el sitio. Una pregunta debe tener respuestas objetivas y decir "la herramienta X es la mejor" no es objetiva, puede que en un par de meses aparezca una mejor herramienta u otra existente brinda más opciones mejores para tu escenario. También puede que la herramienta que para ti sea la mejor no aplique para necesidades de otros usuarios, por ello no hay una objetividad en este tipo de casos.

Comment: No te procupes hugo, a todos nos pasa al principio, y de nuevo la invitación para para que nos acompañes a hablar de este tema en la sala de [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) y recordar que estas reglas estan para mejorar la calidad del contenido del sitio y sea mas util para todos. Ademas esto lleva años aplicandose en la versión en ingles

Comment: Hola @Luiggi Mendoza la pregunta tiene 3 partes, el problema creo que está en el punto a) en mi investigación del tema pude observar que muchas personas listan varios aplicativos que prometen ofuscar el código, luego al probarlos observe que lo que ofrecian era mucho más que lo que realmente hacian (mentian), entonces con la pregunta lo que estoy buscando son programadores que realmente usen alguna herramienta de ofuscación que me expliquen que conjunto de herramientas usan y les han dado exito

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, en dicha investigación-busqueda tambien encontré que la solución es mezclar código en .net y c++/cli, si bien c++ tambien tiene programas que lo descompilan aún no es con la claridad que lo hace ILSPY con los productos .net, pero como explico no he encontrado mucha información al respecto y eso creo que es una necesidad de las personas que busquen lo que yo, entonces en parte pregunto y en parte comparto lo que encontré y serán los usuarios quienes aportaran sus experiencias que creo que es el objetivo de SO

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, yo ya busqué un ofuscador de código y lo que explico es mi experiencia al usarlos, y como todo en informatica es valido HOY pero mañana todo cambiara, mismo una solución hoy para un problema y que lleve varias hojas de codigo, mañana quedará obsoleta por una nueva libreria que con una sola linea de código haga lo mismo, TODAS las respuestas son válidas HOY, y según la experiencia del programador puede ser una u otra. estoy buscando las experiencias de los usuarios y la opción del chat no es valida, no permite encontrar respuestas y que las misma pueda ser aprovechada por otros

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, para los programadores de .net que venden sus programas y estos funcionan en la maquina del cliente es muy importante este tema, la importancia es tan grande que supera todo otro tipo de argumentación, creo que ese aspecto no lo estas tomando en cuenta. Yo como programador novato en .net llegue a determinadas conclusiones pero tengo digamos "inseguridad" y quiero plantear este tema que creo que es "permanente" y donde todo lo que se hable va a ser poco, y es importante que lo que se hable quede para posteriores consultas, por lo que te solicito que desbloquees mi pregunta

Comment: @jasilva, por lo argumentado anteriormente, te solicito me informes como hacer para que se desbloquee la pregunta

Comment: Hola Hugo, cuando consideres que una pregunta cerrada debe abrirse, hay un boton justo a la izquierda de los datos de la persona que pregunta `|compartir|editar|reabrir|eliminar|reportar|` para solicitar su revision para ser reabierta, esta pregunta pasara a una votación por los miembros de la comunidad para **dejarla cerrada** o **reabrirla** aunque no recuerdo si se necesita cierta reputación para poder tener habilitada esta opción

Comment: @jasilva, no tengo esa opción, cual sería otra opción ?

Comment: A pues seria contactar con un moderador, pero, en este caso, eso ya se hizo y el opino que este tema [no cumple la politica](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23567/ofuscar-el-c%c3%b3digo-en-c?noredirect=1#comment39565_23567)

Answer (score 2):

Cualquier ofuscador que apliques al codigo va agenerar cierta complejidad a la persona que quiera analizar o armar el codigo en base a los assembly, no veo porque buscar la perfeccion, ya que no cualquiera podra entender y rearmar un proyecto o libreria en base a codigo ofuscado.

**>>He probado varios programas que encriptan el ejecutable y se desencripta en memoria mientras se ejecutan pero no funcionan con .net, si ustedes saben de alguno que sí funcione, por favor comentenlo ?**

Intentaste con

[PC Guard for .NET64](http://www.sofpro.com/products/pc-guard-net64)

ademas de aplicar proteccion genera un sistem de licencias.

**>>Buscando en internet encontré que es posible escribir parte del código en c++/cli y hacer un wrapper con c#.**

No se a que llamaras wrapper pero eso no existe entre una libreria e .net y otro de c++, puedes invocar funcionalidad creada en c++ pero sera por medio de codigo no manajado

La verdad no recomiendo para nada este camino, si puedes evitalo

**>>Conocen un ejemplo en que se pueda ver como usar c++/cli y hacer un wrapper con c#.**

primero deberias ver como poder crear la libreria en c++

[Tutorial: Crear y utilizar una biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms235636.aspx)

para invocarla usarias el [DllImport]

[Tutorial de invocación de la plataforma](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx)

como veras esto no es ningun wrapper, sino que invocas la libreria de c++ desde .net declarando la firma, pero al ser codigo no manejado, si puedes evitalo

Comment: Esta respuesta luce más como un comentario largo que no cabe en los 500 caracteres.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza porque un comentario largo? le estoy respondiendo a las preguntas planteadas en la pregunta, son varios temas que trata. Que tipo de respuesta le hubieras dado? o lo dejarias sin respuesta?

Comment: No hubiese brindado una respuesta porque esta pregunta es demasiado amplia y se presta para un debate. Los debates no son beneficiosos para el sitio. Para ello, existen las salas de chat. Allí sí existe la libertad para las conversaciones largas y tendidas, discusiones, debates, etc.